# Sonar for Eclipse: unable to run local analysis

Tags: eclipse-plugin, sonarqube

I have successfully installed sonar plug-in for eclipse, however when I try to 'Run Local Analysis' for sonar, eclipse gives an error saying:

`An internal error occurred during: "Sonar Analysis".

Unable to create markers`

and console for Sonar has following info printed:

```
Usage: javaw [-options] class [args...]
           (to execute a class)
   or  javaw [-jar] [-options] jarfile [args...]
           (to execute a jar file)

where options include:
    -cp -classpath 
              set search path for application classes and resources
    -D=
              set a system property
    -verbose[:class|gc|jni]
              enable verbose output
    -version  print product version
    -version:
        require the specified version to run
    -showversion  print product version and continue
    -jre-restrict-search | -no-jre-restrict-search
              include/exclude user private JREs in the version search
    -agentlib:[=]
              load native agent library , e.g. -agentlib:hprof
              see also, -agentlib:jdwp=help and -agentlib:hprof=help
    -agentpath:[=]
              load native agent library by full pathname
    -javaagent:[=]
              load Java programming language agent, see java.lang.instrument
    -? -help  print this help message
    -X        print help on non-standard options
    -splash:  show splash screen with specified image
    -ea[:...|:]
    -enableassertions[:...|:]
              enable assertions
    -da[:...|:]
    -disableassertions[:...|:]
              disable assertions
    -esa | -enablesystemassertions
              enable system assertions
    -dsa | -disablesystemassertions
              disable system assertions
```

Plz help with how to proceed for Local analysis in eclipse.

**[Update: Version Details]**
Eclipse: Indigo (3.7.1)
Sonar Plug-in: 3.0.0
Sonar(Server): 3.4.1
Sonar Web Service Client: 3.4.0
Java: 1.4.1 ('Java EE IDE' property in Eclipse Features)
Local Java Installation: 1.6

Comment: Have you installed the latest version of the Sonar Eclipse plugin?

Comment: Yes, I am able to connect to server and see result. Problem occurs only with Local Analysis.

Comment: Can you please precisely detail your environment? (edit your question to add this information: verison of eclipse, version of sonar, version of Java, ...etc)

Comment: @Fabrice-SonarTeam: Updated the question with required data. Let me know if you need something else.

Comment: What do you get when you run "java -version" in a shell?

Comment: java version: 1.6.0_31  Also, I am trying it on windows machine.